# How can I know plugins versions for a given version of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I am developping a plugin for eclipse, and I am trying to find the minimum compatible version for my plugin dependencies.

As a rule of thumb, I would say my plugin should be compatible with all Luna versions. But **how do I know which were the versions of the plugins in the first version of Luna ? I wouldn't mind an approximate answer.**

I believe my plugin dependencies are available in all Luna distributions :

- org.eclipse.core.runtime
- org.eclipse.jdt.core
- org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui
- org.eclipse.jdt.launching
- org.eclipse.jdt.ui
- org.eclipse.jface.text
- org.eclipse.debug.ui
- org.eclipse.ui
- org.eclipse.ui.console
- org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor
- org.objectweb.asm

Thanks in advance

Comment: Download the original luna release and check? (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/luna/r)

Comment: Well that might not be the fastest way but that's one solution ! Thanks

Comment: 'org.objectweb.asm' isn't part of core Eclipse, all the others have existing since Eclipse 3.2 at the latest (probably a lot earlier).

Answer (score 2):

Refer this [blog](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/manifestmf-and-featurexml) for dependency plug-in version ranges. In your case mention the minimum version as 0.0.0. Also check [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=481864&seqNum=3)

Open your plugin.xml in PDE editor, switch to **Dependency** tab then select a plugin then click on **Properties** button. Enter minimum versions as 0.0.0. Do this all dependent plugins.
[image]

Check your Manifest.mf file it look like

`Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="[0.0.0)"`

Note: Also note that refer the API changes between the different version of dependent plugin(s) and check how these changes affects your plugin code.

---

In case you want to know the exact versions of all plug-ins in a given eclipse simultaneous release then go to this [link](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/) download appropriate package.
Open eclipse. Go to Help > About eclipse. Click on Installation details. Switch to Plug-ins tab the check the versions here.

Comment: If you want to see the original version of my dzone post, it's here: http://divby0.blogspot.com.co/2011/07/manifestmf-and-featurexml-versioning.html